# Multiple dropdowns tied to each other in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Right now I have three dropdown menus. Only the first dropdown menu is shown upon page loading. Once an option from that menu is selected, the second menu appears. I'm trying to do the same with the second and third menu, but it's not working. Below is the HTML and JS code that I have, what am I doing wrong?

```js
function choose() {
  if (document.getElementById('filter1').value == 'genre') {
    document.getElementById('items').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('items2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('items3').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('items4').style.display = 'none';


  } else if (document.getElementById('filter1').value == 'year') {
    document.getElementById('items').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('items2').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('items3').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('items4').style.display = 'none';
  } else if (document.getElementById('filter1').value == 'director') {
    document.getElementById('items').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('items2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('items3').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('items4').style.display = 'none';
  } else if (document.getElementById('filter1').value == 'actor') {
    document.getElementById('items').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('items2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('items3').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('items4').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('items').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('items2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('items3').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('items4').style.display = 'none';
  }


}

function check() {
  if (document.getElementById('items').style.display == 'block') {
    document.getElementById('filter').style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <select id="filter1" name="filter1" onclick="choose()">
    <option value=NULL>Filter 1</option>
    <option value="genre">Genre</option>
    <option value="year">Year</option>
    <option value="director">Director name</option>
    <option value="actor">Actor name</option>
    <!-- Insert function to call server -->
    </select>

  </div>


</div>


<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <select id="items" name="items" style="display: none">
    <option value=NULL>Filter 2</option>
    <option value="year">Year</option>
    <option value="director">Director name</option>
    <option value="actor">Actor name</option>
    </select>
    <select id="items2" name="items" style="display: none">
    <option value=NULL>Filter 2</option>
    <option value="genre">Genre</option>
    <option value="director">Director name</option>
    <option value="actor">Actor name</option>
    </select>
    <select id="items3" name="items" style="display: none">
    <option value=NULL>Filter 2</option>
    <option value="genre">Genre</option>
    <option value="year">Year</option>
    <option value="actor">Actor name</option>
    </select>
    <select id="items4" name="items" style="display: none">
    <option value=NULL>Filter 2</option>
    <option value="genre">Genre</option>
    <option value="year">Year</option> 
    <option value="director">Director name</option>
    </select>


  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <select id="filter" name="filter" style="display: none">
    <option value=NULL>Filter 3</option>
    <option value="2">Director name</option>
    <option value="3">Actor name</option>
    </select>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Define "not working".  Where/how specifically does it fail?  When you debug this, where does it go wrong?  What happens and what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: There are no click events bound to the 3 other selects.

Comment: Another suggestion: if you replace the ids items, items2, items3, items4 to dropdown_genre, dropdown_year, dropdown_director and dropdown_genre, your if/else block can be completely removed, since the value of `document.getElementById('filter1').value` will give you the id of the dropdown to show instead of ahving to check each value seperately.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is not working ? I noticed that you use the label "filter 2" for the default option on #items, #items2, #items3 and #items4 which can be confusing.

I tried with this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rd2b6h46/1/) and it seems to work.

The only modifications done are :

- I added some logs
- I used `window.choose = function choose() {...}`. But this should not be an issue as the choose function should already be attached to the window object.

Comment: Actually I have a doubt, do you need to display only two dropdowns or do you want to display a new dropdown each time the previous one is filled ?

Answer (score 0):

There is only an event bound to the first dropdown: `<select id="filter1" name="filter1" onclick="choose()">`

*There are no events bound to the other selects.*

So you need to add the same functionality to the second dropdown as well to get it to work. As written, there's nothing wrong with the code logically: show one of the second dropdowns once the first dropdown is changed and do nothing once any other dropdown is changed.